# UI Issue with kal calendar for ipad iOS 10

Tags: ios, calendar, kal

I'm using Kal calendar, which is open source. The issue here is dates are not rendering properly with iOS 10. Please let me know if you have solution or what is causing the issue.

screenshot: https://github.com/klazuka/Kal/issues/106

Thanks

Comment: Hmm. That's a pretty old library. It was last updated 4 years ago. Does it work well for iOS 9?

Comment: Yes, It works in iOS9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the system font name. I replaced
`UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:fontSize];`
with
`UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];`
in KalTileView to get it working.

Comment: Thanks David.. Your solution works fine. In the same KalTileView there are   deprecated methods CGContextSelectFont and CGContextShowTextAtPoint. So, I was trying to replace the deprecated methods with "NSFontAttributeName". I could see the dates after changing the methods but the date(number) is reversed upside down. Xcode is not showing "boldSystemFontOfSize" as deprecated.

Comment: This also works fine, which is alternate to the deprecated methods. [dayText drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(textX, textY) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"  size:17]}];

Comment: @selva I'd also like to replace the deprecated methods but the drawAtPoint is not placing the day numbers correctly for me. They are infringing up on the day markers.
Indeed I didn't meant to indicate boldSystemFontOfSize was deprecated, only that replacing it solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

To David: Thanks for your solution as well.

To Selva: I tried to replace CGContextShowTextAtPoint by drawAtPoint and also got upside down problem. Then i add below to fix this, hope this helps

```
  CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
  CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.height);
  CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0f, -1.0f);

  [YourTextString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(X, Y) withAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}];

  CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

Comment: Yes this works. But in my case dates background color got changed.

Answer (score 0):

system font not working.Try to use below code.

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize];
in KalTileView to get it working.